# Android: Webview turns out to be white in color after html/javascript loaded.

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, hardware-acceleration, android-hardware

Working on the webview on Android 4.0 and above sets the webview color as white after a html/javascript page is loaded onto it.

After i went to developer options and unchecked the FORCE GPU RENDERING. After this it works fine. But when i do it programatically  via

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
```

Both in application and activity. and also via `webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

This does not work via code.
Help needed, Thanks